# Listener consuming keys even off canvas?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, keylistener

I have a game I made in canvas that listens for w,a,d and the arrows keys.
However when I go off the canvas and click the "Click here to subscribe" button below the canvas and try to type in w,a or d then they wont type.

Im using JQuery for the button and HTML5 Canvas for the game.

WHat is causing this and any idea how to stop it?
Is there a way I can stop the listener when the button is clicked and start it again when 
the JQuery screen is closed?

Here it is: http://www.slimedrop.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're listening for key events on the whole window.

You can allow your canvas itself to receive key events by setting its tab index.

Then listen for key events on your canvas, instead of on the window.

Then the canvases key handler will no longer receive key events when the user changes focus to your subscription form.

```
    // get a reference to the canvas
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');

    // set canvas to be a tab stop (necessary to get keydown events)
    canvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');

    // have handleKeydown handle keydown events on the canvas
    canvas.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeydown,false);

    // set focus to the canvas so keystrokes are immediately handled
    canvas.focus();
```

Comment: I'm using document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {checkKeyDown(e);}
Is there a way to make it so its the canvas instead of the document?

Comment: Yes, the code above will let you handle key events from just the canvas.  Just set the tabindex and listen on your canvas.  canvas.addEventListener('keydown',yourKeyDownHandler,false);